# Previous result in Chez Scheme

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, chez-scheme

In the Chez Scheme REPL, is it possible to get the previous result?  For example in ruby's irb repl, underscore can be used.

For example can I do the following?

```
> (+ 2 3)
5
> (+ 1 <something>)
```

And get 6?

Answer (score 1):

Chez Scheme does not have a built in way to do this, but being scheme, we can roll our own:

```
(define repl
  (let ([n 1])
    (lambda (expr)
      (let-values ([vals (eval expr)])
        (for-each (lambda (v)
                    (unless (eq? (void) v)
                      (let ([sym (string->symbol (format "$~a" n))])
                        (set! n (+ n 1))
                        (printf "~a = " sym)
                        (pretty-print v)
                        (set-top-level-value! sym v))))
          vals)))))

(new-cafe repl)
```

`repl` is now a function that takes an expression, evaluates it, stores the non-void results into ids of the form `$N` where N is monotonically increasing, and prints out the results. `new-cafe` is a standard chez function that manages the Reading, Printing, and Looping parts of REPL. It takes a function that manages the Evaluation part. In this case, `repl` also needs to manage printing since it shows the ids associated with the values.

Edit:

I found a slightly better way to do this. Instead of having a custom repl, we can customize only the printer. Now this function is no longer responsible for also evaluating the input.

```
(define write-and-store
  (let ([n 1])
    (lambda (x)
      (unless (eq? (void) x)
        (let ([sym (string->symbol (format "$~a" n))])
          (set! n (+ n 1))
          (set-top-level-value! sym x)
          (printf "~a = " sym)
          (pretty-print x)
          (flush-output-port (console-output-port)))))))

(waiter-write write-and-store)
```

A simple usage example:

```
> (values 1 2 3 4)
$1 = 1
$2 = 2
$3 = 3
$4 = 4
> (+ $1 $2 $3 $4)
$5 = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you edit your answer to include how to use it? e.g. `(+ 1 $23)`